# Classic ASP on IIS7: ADODB.Stream error File could not be opened - accessing outside the webroot

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, stream, ado

I've just reinstalled a server, it is a new machine, same OS verion (Win2008) and same IIS version (7.0). The app was working perfectly (and then the machine blew up).

I'm getting this error when I try to access a file outside the webroot:

ADODB.Stream error '800a0bba' File could not be opened

I can access it fine using FileSystemObject, but cannot open it with ADODB.Stream.

Also, I can create a PDF using abcPDF, but I cannot create one again with the same name and overwrite it (this used to work). This works fine inside the website folder structure but not outside.

Also, I cannot attach a file using JMail any more. This applies to files BOTH inside and outside the webroot. So that is weird.

I've assigned Full Control to Everyone on the whole drive to isolate whether it is a permissions problem and it made no difference.

Any ideas anyone?

**UPDATE:** The problem with attaching files inside the site does not appear to be happening any more, since I mucked round with several things. I'm not sure what did it unfortunately. I got nowhere on this and lost hours over it, so I ended up move all the files inside the webroot and now everything works. This is not ideal and I would still like to get to the bottom of it, but the workaround is acceptable.

Updated question as I accidentally wrote Win2003 instead of 2008.

Comment: Windows 2003/IIS6 or Windows 2008/IIS7 which?  The configuration of Windows 2003/IIS7 is not possible.

Comment: Yes you are right it is Windows 2008, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with attaching files inside the site does not appear to be happening any more, since I mucked round with several things. I'm not sure what did it unfortunately. I got nowhere on this and lost hours over it, so I ended up move all the files inside the webroot and now everything works. This is not ideal and I would still like to get to the bottom of it, but the workaround is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the from your database in the first place how you save the PDF file in question. That is where you saved the file in question into the database from the same machine or from a remote machine. Usually when you save from the same developer machine and you are accessing there will be no error but when the file was saved from a machine other than the developer machine, then you will have such error.

For example:

```
'1. dbSignatureImage = New ADODB.Stream
'2. dbSignatureImage.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary
'3. dbSignatureImage.Open()
'4. dbSignatureImage.

LoadFromFile(dbRecordSet.Fields("client_signature_filename").Value)
```

From the above code, I was trying to display two different images from the database (one at a time) and among the two images I saved one directly from the developer machine and the other image was saved from a different PC over my network. Whenever I try displaying the second image which was saved from a network PC, then I have the error of file could not be opened. Now what I did was commenting the 4th line and the error seized but then the image was not displaying so I tried displaying the image itself directly from the BLOB field using IO.MemoryStream with the following codes and it is working fine for both the developer machine and any PC over the network.

```
Dim PassportImageArray() As Byte = CType(dbRecordSet.Fields("client_passport_image").Value, Byte())
Dim SignatureImageArray() As Byte = CType(dbRecordSet.Fields("client_signature_image").Value, Byte())

Dim PassportImageMemoryStream As New MemoryStream(PassportImageArray)
Dim SignatureImageMemoryStream As New MemoryStream(SignatureImageArray)

With picSearchPhotograph
.Image = Image.FromStream(PassportImageMemoryStream)
.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
End With
```

I think you can go round your problem with this my small idea. I hope it will you some how.

Kasapa-Sunyani

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take a closer look at the security permissions on the folders outside of your applications home folder.  Also take a look at the what user identity is actually used to run your code, for example do you have windows integrated security turned on?  If not, is that true of the previous server?

It might help if we could know for sure whether this really is an IIS7 question in which case your server is 2008 not 2003.  You might also find that this sort of thing is best handled by the [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) people.

Comment: It is Win2008+IIS7. How do I check on windows integrated security?